# PyCharm can't find 'keysm' in 'event' (Python 3.9 PyCharm 2020.3.3)

Tags: python, tkinter, pycharm, python-3.9

I recently tried making a submarine game and made about 132 lines of code. I run the code and pressed the specified keys to move the submarine. Errors came up in the Shell that `event` doesn't have attribute `keysm`. Could anyone tell what I am supposed to replace `event` with or correct `keysm`?

Full Code:

```
from tkinter import *
from random import randint
from time import sleep, time
from math import sqrt

HEIGHT = 500
WIDTH = 800
window = Tk()
bub_id = list()
bub_r = list()
bub_speed = list()
MIN_BUB_R = 10
MAX_BUB_R = 30
MAX_BUB_SPD = 10
GAP = 100
window.title('Bubble Blaster')
c = Canvas(window, width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT, bg='darkblue')
c.pack()
ship_id = c.create_polygon(5, 5, 5, 25, 30, 15, fill='red')
ship_id2 = c.create_oval(0, 0, 30, 30, outline='red')
SHIP_R = 15
MID_X = WIDTH / 2
MID_Y = HEIGHT / 2
SHIP_SPD = 10
BUB_CHANCE = 10
time_text = c.create_text(50, 50, fill='white')
score_text = c.create_text(150, 50, fill='white')
TIME_LIMIT = 30
BONUS_SCORE = 1000
score = 0
bonus = 0
end = time() + TIME_LIMIT

c.move(ship_id, MID_X, MID_Y)
c.move(ship_id2, MID_X, MID_Y)


def move_ship(event):
    if event.keysm == 'Up':
        c.move(ship_id, 0, -SHIP_SPD)
        c.move(ship_id2, 0, -SHIP_SPD)
    elif event.keysm == 'Down':
        c.move(ship_id, 0, SHIP_SPD)
        c.move(ship_id2, 0, SHIP_SPD)
    elif event.keysm == 'Left':
        c.move(ship_id2, -SHIP_SPD, 0)
        c.move(ship_id2, -SHIP_SPD, 0)
    elif event.keysm == 'Right':
        c.move(ship_id, SHIP_SPD, 0)
        c.move(ship_id2, SHIP_SPD, 0)
c.bind_all('<Key>', move_ship)


def create_bubble():
    x = WIDTH + GAP
    y = randint(0, HEIGHT)
    r = randint(MIN_BUB_R, MAX_BUB_R)
    id1 = c.create_oval(x - r, y - r, x + r, y + r, outline='white')
    bub_id.append(id1)
    bub_r.append(r)
    bub_speed.append(randint(1, MAX_BUB_SPD))


def move_bubbles():
    for i in range(len(bub_id)):
        c.move(bub_id[i], -bub_speed[i], 0)


def get_coords(id_num):
    pos = c.coords(id_num)
    x = (pos[0] + pos[2])/2
    y = (pos[1] + pos[3])/2
    return x, y


def distance(id1, id2):
    x1, y1 = get_coords(id1)
    x2, y2 = get_coords(id2)
    return sqrt((x2 - x1)**2 + (y2 - y1)**2)


def del_bubble(i):
    del bub_r[i]
    del bub_speed[i]
    c.delete(bub_id[i])
    del bub_id[i]


def collision():
    points = 0
    for bub in range(len(bub_id)-1, -1, -1):
        if distance(ship_id2, bub_id[bub]) < (SHIP_R + bub_r[bub]):
            points += (bub_r[bub] + bub_speed[bub])
            del_bubble(bub)
    return points


def show_score(score):
    c.itemconfig(score_text, text=str(score))


def show_time(time_left):
    c.itemconfig(time_text, text=str(time_left))


def clean_up_bubs():
    for i in range(len(bub_id)-1, -1, -1):
        x, y = get_coords(bub_id[i])
        if x < -GAP:
            del_bubble(i)


c.create_text(50, 30, text='TIME', fill='white')
c.create_text(150, 30, text='SCORE', fill='white')


#MAIN GAME LOOP
while time() < end:
    if randint(1, BUB_CHANCE) == 1:
        create_bubble()
    move_bubbles()
    clean_up_bubs()
    score += collision()
    if (int(score / BONUS_SCORE)) > bonus:
        bonus += 1
        end += TIME_LIMIT
    show_score(score)
    show_time(int(end - time()))
    window.update()
    sleep(0.01)
```

Comment: What is the type of  `event`? Perhaps it's not what you think it is. What do you get if you do `print(event)` or `print(type(event))`?

Comment: PyCharm says it's an unresolved reference. I have no idea what `event` is supposed to do because I saw it in a tutorial.

Comment: Typo, it should be `event.keysym`.

Comment: `event` is still an unresolved reference

Comment: Don't mind `pycharm`, what does it show when you run the code. Also how do you trigger this function.

Comment: I can't not mind PyCharm. I ran the code and it said the error that `event` is an unresolved reference.

Comment: How do you call the function.

Comment: I called it `move_ship`

Comment: I wrote `c.bind_all('<Key>', move_ship)` to activate the function

Comment: It should be working, is this function used in some button or so?

Comment: I don't understand?

Comment: Is this function used with some button? That could so create some problem,

Comment: Of course. Up arrow = Up, Down arrow = Down, Side arrows = Sideways

Comment: Please post the entire error code in the question

Comment: Posted the full code.

Comment: After fixing the typo, changing EVERY `event.kysm` to `event.kysym`. It works.

Comment: it still doesn't work